# JSON encode firstname + Lastname = fullname

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to merge firstname and lastname together as fullname

```
$record[0]["firstname"]="foo";
$record[0]["lastname"]="bar";
$record[0]["age"]="20";

for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {

    $foobar_array[] = array(
            'fullname' => [$record[$i]['firstname'], $record[$i]['lastname']],
            'age' => $record[$i]['age']

    );


}

echo json_encode($foobar_array);
```

I want the json string to display

```
[{"fullname":"foo bar ","age":"20"}]
```

Comment: use join array_join as i rememeber into php

Comment: `'fullname' => $record[$i]['firstname'] . ' ' . $record[$i]['lastname']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$foobar_array[] = array(
     'fullname' => $record[$i]['firstname'] . ' ' . $record[$i]['lastname'],
      'age' => $record[$i]['age']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$record = [
    [
        'firstname' => 'foo',
        'lastname' => 'bar',
        'age' => 20,
    ]
];

foreach ($record as $r) {
    $foobar_array[] = [
            'fullname' => $r['firstname'].' '.$r['lastname'],
            'age' => $r['age']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($foobar_array);
```

->

```
[{"fullname":"foo bar","age":"20"}]
```